# Change element i PriorityQueues

Tags: java

I am building an easy priorityQueue with `Patients` as `Object` which look like this:

```
patientQueue.add(new Patient(id, name, emergencyNr));
```

I have menu-choice where i can add new patients. But now I need to add a choice  to do this:

- search and check for a specific name in each `Patients`.
- If the name of the Patient is in the patientQueue, then I want to change the emergencyNr (priority) from example 1 to 3.
- If the name not in the `Queue` i need to handle it with a message

How can I search for name and then change the priority in that `Patient`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through your Queue. Then check if object.name.equals("yourString"). If true then object.setEmergenceyNr(newPriority). Where newPriority is an int. This implies that you have setters and getters for your Object. Also it would be good to have the iterable interface implemented to your queue such that you can apply foreach.

Comment: I have setters and getters. Can you please make me and example code how to iterate thorough the queue?

Comment: what about foreach. Do you have the iterable interface implemented? If yes you could simply do: (for Object x:yourQueue)

Comment: if not check it out here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/implementing-iterable.html

Comment: Thanks so far, 
I wrote this but got a problem: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setEmergencyCase(int) from the type Patient"

                                    `for (Patient e : patientQueue)
    if (Patient.getName().equals(name) == true){
     Patient.setEmergencyCase(9)     
    }´

And i cant make the method static because of "this.emergencyNr..."
                           ´ public void setEmergencyCase(int emergencyCase) {
  this.emergencyNr = emergencyNr;
 }´

You know how to fix?

Comment: first of all this public void setEmergencyCase(int emergencyCase) { this.emergencyNr = emergencyNr; } shoud be:public void setEmergencyCase(int emergencyCase) { this.emergencyNr =  emergencyCase; }

Comment: also here:  for (Patient e : patientQueue) if (Patient.getName().equals(name) == true){ Patient.setEmergencyCase(9) }. You should have this: for (Patient e : patientQueue) if (e.getName().equals(name) == true){ e.setEmergencyCase(9) }

Comment: e is your newly assigned Patient variable. Patient is the object itself not an instance of that object.

Comment: that was your problem. You can't know which emergencyNr you are refering to as you are not trying to get one from an instance of your class. Give it another try, it should work now...